# Pulling multiple records with a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some code here working well with an outer join.

It just appends a record from another table with a common field (entity-id) but for a specific record type "87".

My problem is that I want to also pull additional individual records from the same table with other record types "178" and "675" in the same SELECT statement.

Can I achieve this with a JOIN, or am I barking up the wrong tree????

```
SELECT
    tempdb.Entity_id,
    tempdb.SKU,
    tempdb.Description,
    Entity_Varchar.value AS ImageURL
FROM
    tempdb
LEFT OUTER JOIN Entity_Varchar ON tempdb.entity_id = Entity_Varchar.entity_id AND Entity_Varchar.attribute_id = '87'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please can you show an example using actual data. It can and should be fictitious data, sufficient to demonstrate the behaviour you require.  This explains why... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: please share sample data and output expected from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the filtering condition for the record types you want:

```
SELECT t.Entity_id, t.SKU, t.Description,
       ev.value AS ImageURL
FROM tempdb t LEFT JOIN
     Entity_Varchar ev
     ON t.entity_id = ev.entity_id AND
        ev.attribute_id IN ('87', '178', '675');
```

Comment: Thanks. I get than I can extend the record type selection, but the problem is that I need to include the results in the SELECT statement results, and I have no way of referencing the results. I'm thinking that I might have to use nested SELECT statements perhaps? ev.value will only return the selected record type.